# Arithmetic Operation in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    float arithmetic_operation = (4+5)+9*2-4+2/5+1-13;
    cout<< arithmetic_operation << " <--The Result." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting 11 <--The Result. But actually the result is 11.4, Can someone please help me to understand the point please.

Comment: You're doing far too much too early. Start with a much simpler program and make sure that every part of what you're doing actually behaves as you expect. In order to run you first need to learn how to walk!

Comment: `2/5 == 0`. At least one operand of a division must be a floating-point type, otherwise it's an integer division, truncating towards zero. E.g. `2.0 / 5`, or `2 / 5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing *integer arithmetic*. All operands are integers, which meand all operations will be done using integer operations. And for integer division `2/5` is equal to zero.

Use floating point value all over instead:

```
double arithmetic_operation = (4.+5.)+9.*2.-4.+2./5.+1.-13.;
```

Comment: but I have declared a float variable.. and the answer is 11.4 which is a float variable.

Comment: @rashedazad Yes but that doesn't matter. The value `2` is an integer, as is `5`. Dividing two integers will result in another integer, and integers can't have decimals. You must use floating-point literals instead of integer literals.

Comment: @rashedazad: All this is done long before your float variable has anything to do with it. Only the end result goes in the float variable. By then you've already messed up :)